# finding nested span and <dt> with XPath in HTML

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a piece of html (just a chunk of it is presented here) like this:

```
<div class='games'>
    Won <span class="text-success">37</span>,
    lost <span class="text-error">51</span>,
    ratio <span>42.05</span>%
</div>
<div class='race'>
    Favorite Race:
    <div class='race-terran races size-16'></div>
    <span>Terran</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class='span3 ranks'>
    <dl class='dl-horizontal'>
        <dt>
            <div class='flag-global flags size-16'></div>
            World Rank:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            #<span>6,654</span>
            of
            <span>58,431</span>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <div class='flag-eu flags size-16'></div>
            Region Rank:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            #<span>2,679</span>
            of
            <span>23,944</span>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Bonus Pool:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            9
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div class='span3 ext-stats'>
    <dl class='dl-horizontal'>
        <dt class='wide'>
            <a href="/team/eu/11001756782/stimphano" class="alt">View Team Page</a>
        </dt>
        <dd></dd>
        <dt>Last Game:</dt>
        <dd>19 hours ago</dd>
        <dt>Last Update:</dt>
        <dd>6 hours ago</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I have to read things like 'won, lost, ratio' as well as other things. the first three items are easily reachable using the code below:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(_sc2RanksString);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");

var won = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='games']/*[@class='text-success']").InnerText;
var lost = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='games']/*[@class='text-error']").InnerText;
var points = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='points']/*[@class='gold']").InnerText;
var bonusPool =
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='flag-eu flags size-16']//span//span/dt").InnerText;
```

But in the above example, the las line I can not get 'Bonus Pool'...it seems that I provided it with a wrong xpath query.

Can someone tell me how would I reach the bonus pool and region rank X of Y

Further more I need to get last game and last update as well. But I really have difficulties with finding things in  nodes.

Comment: In this case its 2,679 of 23,944 as it is in the html I pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bonusPool = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//div[@class='span3 ranks']/dl[@class='dl-horizontal']//dd")
                .Last()
                .InnerText.Trim();

var regionRank = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//div[@class='span3 ranks']/dl[@class='dl-horizontal']/dd[2]/span")
                .Select(x => x.InnerText)
                .ToArray();


var lastGame = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='span3 ext-stats']/dl[@class='dl-horizontal']/dd[2]")
                .InnerText;

var lastUpdate = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='span3 ext-stats']/dl[@class='dl-horizontal']/dd[3]")
                .InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please add last game and last update to your answer? I still didnt completly got the idea behind XPath in this case but I think I am close :P